# Bad file descriptor in C:\Users\asdfs\OneDrive\bugs\stockfish\code.php on line 18

Tags: php, subprocess

Some posts seem to be running in Unix, but this was run in Windows.

I'm trying to just show the output of an application, like this code:

```php
<html>
<body>
<?php
    $descriptorspec = [
        0 => ["pipe", "w"],  // Write end of pipe for input
        1 => ["pipe", "r+"],  // Read end of pipe for output
        2 => ["pipe", "r+"]   // Read end of pipe for error output
    ];

    $pipes = array();
    $process = proc_open("./stockfish-windows-x86-64.exe", $descriptorspec, $pipes);

    if (is_resource($process)) {
        // Initialize $pipes array

        // Write to stdin
        fwrite($pipes[0], "uci\n");

    $status = proc_get_status($process);
    while (!$status['running'] && feof($pipes[1])) {
                $line = fgets($pipes[1]);
                // Process each line (e.g., print it or store it in an array)
           echo $line;
            $status = proc_get_status($process);
    }
        // Close stdin
        fclose($pipes[0]);

        // Close the process
        proc_close($process);
    } else {
        echo "Failed to create process.";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

But this shows the following error:

> PHP Notice:  fwrite(): Write of 4 bytes failed with errno=9 Bad file descriptor in C:\Users\asdfs\OneDrive\bugs\stockfish\code.php on line 18

Comment: `$pipes` is probably still an empty array. Double-check it before you use it.

Comment: Have you checked the first example in the manual? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php You passed the write end of stdin to the child process, so that you cannot write it in your php process.

Answer (score 1):

After reading example, this is the modified code:

```php
<html>
<body>
<?php
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
);

$cwd = 'C:\Users\asdfs\OneDrive\bugs\stockfish';

$process = proc_open('stockfish-windows-x86-64.exe', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, null);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    // $pipes now looks like this:
    // 0 => writeable handle connected to child stdin
    // 1 => readable handle connected to child stdout
    // Any error output will be appended to /tmp/error-output.txt

    fwrite($pipes[0], 'uci');
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    echo nl2br(stream_get_contents($pipes[1]));
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    // It is important that you close any pipes before calling
    // proc_close in order to avoid a deadlock
    $return_value = proc_close($process);

    echo "command returned $return_value\n";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```